# Trazer dados relacionados em uma tabela

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso trazer as sessões de determinado filme, mas caso haja mais de uma sessão em um mesmo cinema, trazer só um dado e os 2 horarios lado a lado. Alguém tem algum jeito de fazer? É minha primeira aplicação com Asp.Net e estou um pouco perdido. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o método que fiz de acordo com um artigo de exemplo da microsoft, mas ele não resolveu o meu problema, pesquisei sobre ViewModels e não consegui encontrar nada parecido com o que precisava

```
    // GET: Filme
    public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? sessaoID)
    {
        var viewModel = new FilmesIndex();
        viewModel.Filmes = db.Filmes
            .Include(i => i.Cinemas)
            .Include(i => i.Sessoes)
            .OrderBy(i => i.Nome);

       if(id != null)
       {
         ViewBag.SessaoID = id.Value;
          viewModel.Sessoes = viewModel.Filmes.Where(
               i => i.FilmeID == id.Value).Single().Sessoes;
       }

        if(sessaoID != null)
        {
            ViewBag.SessaoID = sessaoID.Value;
            viewModel.Sessoes = viewModel.Cinemas.Where(
                x => x.CinemaID == sessaoID).FirstOrDefault().Sessoes;
        }



        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO-PT, não se esqueça de fazer o [tour] e entender como o site funciona. O ideal é que você adicione um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo ou o que já tentou fazer](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). [Veja também na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Editei e coloquei o método Index do meu controller.